# AWT-EventQueue-0 NullPointerException

Tags: java, database, nullpointerexception, jlist, awt-eventqueue

I'm pretty new to Java, and I'm trying to populate my JList with data from a database. The data is retrieved from the database via the method visKunder() in the Database class.

```
public ArrayList<Kunde> visKunder(){
    String s1 = "select kundenavn, adresse, telefon from kunde";
    Statement setning = null;
    String kundenavn = null;
    String adresse = null;
    int telefon = 0;
    ResultSet res = null;
    ArrayList<Kunde> kunder = new ArrayList<>();
    try{
        forbindelse.setAutoCommit(false);
        setning = forbindelse.createStatement();
        res = setning.executeQuery(s1);
        while(res.next()){
            kundenavn = res.getString("kundenavn");
            adresse = res.getString("adresse");
            telefon = res.getInt("telefon");
            Kunde kunde = new Kunde(kundenavn, telefon, adresse);
            kunder.add(kunde);
        }
        forbindelse.commit();
    }catch(SQLException error){
        Opprydder.rullTilbake(forbindelse);
        Opprydder.skrivMelding(error, "visKunder()");
    }finally{
        Opprydder.lukkSetning(setning);
        Opprydder.lukkResSet(res);
        try {
            forbindelse.setAutoCommit(true);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Opprydder.skrivMelding(ex, "setAutoCommit()");
        }
    }
    return kunder;

}
```

The problem occurs when I invoke visKunder() in the GUI class RegVedKjøp. printStackTrace() lists visKunder() as the problem for the NullPointerException.

```
public class RegVedKjøp extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private static Database d1;

public RegVedKjøp(Database d1) {
    initComponents();
    this.d1 = d1;
}
private void initComponents(){
    ...
    JList jList2 = new JList();
    fyllListe(jList2);
    ...
}
private void fyllListe(JList list){
   ArrayList<Kunde> kunder = d1.visKunder(); 
   list = new JList(kunder.toArray());
}
```

I don't know if it's relevant, but I used NetBeans' GUI Builder to design the GUI.
Any tips on how to fix this issue would be very appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
    private void initComponents() {

    scrollbar1 = new java.awt.Scrollbar();
    lagreKnapp = new javax.swing.JButton();
    tKnapp = new javax.swing.JButton();
    label1 = new java.awt.Label();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtType = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtAntall = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtPris = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jList2 = new JList();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Registrer kjøp av ved - Dagsverket");
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setResizable(false);

    lagreKnapp.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    lagreKnapp.setText("Lagre");
    lagreKnapp.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(95, 50));
    lagreKnapp.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            lagreKnappActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    tKnapp.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    tKnapp.setText("Tilbake");
    tKnapp.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(75, 30));
    tKnapp.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            tKnappActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    label1.setText("label1");

    jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel2.setText("Vedtype:");
    jLabel2.setFocusable(false);
    jLabel2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(70, 25));

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Antall sekker:");
    jLabel1.setFocusable(false);
    jLabel1.setName(""); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(70, 25));

    jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("sansserif", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel3.setText("Pris pr/sekk:");

    jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel4.setText("Kunde:");

    jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("SansSerif", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
    jButton1.setText("Registrer Ny Kunde");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
```

This code is generated by the GUI Builder.
I should also state that the this class is one of several that helps display the GUI. Every class is responsible for one operation requested by the user. They are all collected in a class called Mainpage which is used in the class System which runs the whole program. The first thing done in System is the creation of a Database object, and the connection to the database. This Database object is then what is then used as a parameter in every GUI class.

Comment: which line cased the exception?

Comment: I think it's the ArrayList<Kunde> kunder = d1.visKunder(), but I can't figure out why.

                                                             Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sysbase.RegVedKjøp.fyllListe(RegVedKjøp.java:181)
 at sysbase.RegVedKjøp.initComponents(RegVedKjøp.java:105)
 at sysbase.RegVedKjøp.<init>(RegVedKjøp.java:28)

Comment: yea, but which line is from your code?

Comment: ArrayList<Kunde> kunder = d1.visKunder() i think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d1` is obviously `null`. Why? Well, because you call `fyllListe()` method at the `initComponents()` method, which is prior to the initialization of `d1` field at the constructor, so please just change the order, the proper constructor is:

```
public RegVedKjøp(Database d1) {
    this.d1 = d1;
    initComponents();
}
```

Comment: I will sound like a complete twat, sorry, but how will I do this?

Comment: @user3514879 can you please show more code prior to the call of `fyllListe`?

Comment: Please look at the **EDIT** section in the question for the code, and more information about the general functionality, and structure of the program.

Comment: I mean do you have smth like `RegVedKjøp gui = new RegVedKjøp(<database>)` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes, in the class Mainpage.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have wrote. The most probably cause is that d1 is null.
When the RegVedKjøp is creating. Then the database d1 is null into the class.

If I would be you. I would debug and check if the Database d1 is null or not.
But since you haven't added your stacktrace, it is difficult to say exactly.
There is some variable inside the method visKunde, that also could be null. Since they are created outside of the method.

Comment: You're right, d1 is null when creating the components in initComponents. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Well that depends how the code looks like. 
But the probably cause is that it is not created as it should.
I suggest you look closer into what happends when the Database object is created. 
Then if you can not figure out why. Try google.com.

You will certain find the answer there. 
With the information that is added here. There is no way to be able to give you a corrected answer.